# SQL, PHP & jQuery Dynamic comment system

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, comments

I'm setting up an under construction page for my new website.

I'll try to explain:

- There are 3 Columns side by side
- When a new comment is 'retrieved' it is added to the first column
- For each comment - if bottom > 300px from top of column: copy, delete and prepend to next column (just delete if column:last)

The above I have working fine, but riddle me this:

- How can I do the opposite and add older comments to the end
- A comment can vary in height depending on the message, this means there isn't a fixed amount of comments on show.
- There are 'newer comments' and 'older comments' links. I would like these to retrieve comments posted after or before the newest comment shown or oldest comment shown respectively.

The idea is to repeat the 'retrieve comment' procedure 6 times, getting 6 newer/older comments and prepending/appending to the first/last column respectively. I would need to keep track of the newest comment and oldest comment being displayed for the php script to know which comment to retrieve next (returned via AJAX).

I may have over complicated things but it would be fantastic if anyone can just come up with a solid algorithm for me to follow. I'm not asking anyone to program it for me, that would take the fun out! ;D

My attempt at a drawing:

[image: My attempt at a drawing]

Comment: Would you be able to draw / upload a simple picture to explain what you are trying to accomplish? Suppose you fetch a comment and it gets copied to the next column because it is rather long. Then the next fetched comment is very short.. does it go in the first column or the 2nd one?

Comment: There's a limit of 200 characters, a newer comment would always be put into the first column, which is "shown" using jquery, which expands the 'comment container', this pushes down comments below it, comments are then looped through backwards, if a 'comment container' goes below 300px it is copied, prepended to the next column and expanded again, repeating the same process until the last column where it is simply removed from all columns. That help enough?

Comment: Drawn a diagram for you, as I said I have the first part working fine (adding a comment to the start and sorting them) but I need a way of tracking which are shown and how to achieve the same thing in reverse :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help you, but you can set up an array of objects to track their order and to manage if they are visible or not. When you fetch newer comments, add them to the front of the array using `unshift`, and when you fetch older comments, add them to the end of the array using `push`. You can set this up in the oncomplete callback of your AJAX function. The array might look something like this:

```
var comments = [
                   {id: 'comment8', visible: true},
                   {id: 'comment9', visible: true},
                   ...
                ]
```

The id for each object could correspond to the id of the Comment Container, so you can retrieve these values and use them in your jquery selectors to do whatever you need to do.